# Newtonsoft package is not working in SQL Server job

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, sql-server-2019

I have a script in a SSIS package. The script is for authorizing the API and retrieve the data from an API and upload it to a SQL Server table. For deserializing the JSON data, I'm using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package in the script.

The script is perfectly working when I run it manually through Visual Studio, but when I schedule a job in SQL Server 2019 and run the script through a job, I get an error:

> Could not load Newtonsoft library

I'm using .NET framework 4.7. I have tried with manually put the newtonsoft dll in a particular location and access through SQL Server.

Is there any process to resolve this issue? Please let me know.

I have tried changing the version of Newtonsoft. Tried changing the location both in SQL Server as well as Visual Studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the path when you run it locally to this DLL the same as it is on the server?  Does the user /proxy that is running the job have access to the .dlls?

Comment: Yes the path is same for locally and server and user has access of this path